# how to get the weight and quantity from strings in a list in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.x

I'm new to Python, so I'm confused on how to write the regex pattern to find the corresponding weights and quantities from the following list of strings.

This is what I have been doing so far.

```
import re
string1 = [' (Expiry Date: 30 May 2019) 4 x Organic Infant Goat Milk'
               ' Follow-on Formula 3 400g',
           ' (Expiry on 30 May 2019) 4 x Organic Infant Goat Milk'
               ' Follow-on Formula 2 400g ',
           " [ Bellamy's ] Bellamys Organic Step 3 Toddler Milk Drink"
               " 900g x 6 tins Made In Australia  CARTON DEAL EXPIRE"
               " 06/2019 to 2020",
           ' [[1+1]] FRISO (2) 1.8kg+900g',
           " [[Carton Sales]] Bellamy's Organic Follow-On Formula"
               " Step 2 900g x 6tins",
           ' Dumex Mamil Gold Stage 4 Growing Up Kid Milk Formula'
               ' (850g) x 6',
           ' Wyeth S-26 Promise Gold Stage 4 1.6kg X 6 Tins']

m = [re.search('([0-9.]+[kgG]{1,2})', s).group(0) for s in string1] 
print m
```

My output is like this:

```
['400g', '400g', '900g', '1.8kg', '900g', '850g', '1.6kg']
```

But I would like to get this output:

```
['4x400g', '4x400g', '900gx6', '1.8kg+900g', '900gx6', '850gx6', '1.6kgX6']
```

Is there any way to get this?

Comment: You have a problem in that your strings are not regular enough to be easily served by the same regex... you have mixed `[number]x[number][unit]`, `[number][unit]x[number]` and `[number][unit]+[number][unit]`...

Comment: i know the regex pattern is not right,but is there any way to get this@norok2

Comment: I think you should write 3 separate regex and try them one by one.

Comment: i try it on many ways,i don't get any corresponding reslut.also this is first time im using regex.@norok2

Comment: I don't understand the down-vote. This question satisfies all SO requirements: it's reproducible, it provides input/output/desired output. I would not necessarily up-vote it, but why the down-vote?

Comment: @EliKorvigo I guess the downvote is for the 'code this for me' attitude, and before my first edit of the Q, the input strings were on one massively long line, so formatting was ugly.

Comment: @Alfe fair enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to normalize the quantity in the front:

```
m = ['x'.join(i for i in re.search(r'^(?=.*?(?:(\d+)\s*x\b|\bx\s*(\d+)))?(?=.*?((?:\b[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?(?:kg|g)\b\s*?\+?\s*?)+))', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE).groups() if i) for s in string1]
```

Given your sample input, `m` would become:

```
['4x400g', '4x400g', '6x900g', '1.8kg+900g', '6x900g', '6x850g', '6x1.6kg']
```

Comment: You might want to add some `\s*` around the `+` for sums of weights.  Otherwise `1kg + 4kg` aren't recognized.  And things like `foo 1kg+3kg+ bar` will have a trailing `+`.

Comment: Sure. Should be `\s*?` though, since it would otherwise match an extra space when there is no `+`.

Answer (score 0):

Your task is complex and StackOverflow is not a code-my-stuff site, but maybe this approach can get you along a little:

```
for s in string1:
  print(re.findall(
    r'((?:[0-9]+\s*[xX]\b)'
    r'|(?:\b[xX]\s*[0-9]+)'
    r'|(?:[0-9.]+\s*(?:g|kg)\b))', s))
```

This will print the following output:

```
['4 x', '400g']
['4 x', '400g']
['900g', 'x 6']
['1.8kg', '900g']
['900g', 'x 6']
['850g', 'x 6']
['1.6kg', 'X 6']
```

You will still have to figure out some parts by yourself (e. g. that `1.8kg` and `900g` have a `+` between them in the input) but maybe it helps you.

What typically is done in such a case (e. g. in compilers) is the following:

You write a tokenizer (aka parser) which splits the input into tokens (like words), then you write a lexer which consumes the tokens and produces semantic entities (like sentences).  Here I think the tokens would be ① weights, ② amounts (`x 3` etc.), ③ operators (`+`), and ④ junk (anything else).  Whitespace is typically stripped at this point so the lexer only receives stuff which is *between* the whitespace.  If now the lexer receives a sequence of weight - plus - weight, then it should combine this into one entity.  If there is junk in between, it should ignore the plus (because you don't want `5kg bought at benn's+jerry's or 300g bought on the Internet` to result in `5kg+300g`).

But this sound approach isn't done by Regexp alone and I don't think your task can be solved using regexp alone.